# How to assign a type to a list of required function arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code

```js
  poolContract.on(
    "Swap",
    (sender, recipient, amount0, amount1, sqrtPriceX96, liquidity, tick) => {
      console.log({
        sender: sender,
        receipient: recipient,
        amount0: ethers.utils.formatUnits(amount0, 6),
        amount1: ethers.utils.formatUnits(amount1, 18),
        sqrtPriceX96: sqrtPriceX96,
        liquidity: liquidity,
        tick: tick,
      });
    }
  );
```

I want to assign this type to the function arguments:

```js
export type Swap = {
  sender: string;
  recipient: string;
  amount0: BigNumber;
  amount1: BigNumber;
  sqrtPriceX96: BigNumber;
  liquidity: BigNumber;
  tick: number;
};
```

When I perform

```js
  poolContract.on(
    "Swap",
    (swap: Swap) => {
      console.log({
        sender: sender,
        receipient: recipient,
        amount0: ethers.utils.formatUnits(amount0, 6),
        amount1: ethers.utils.formatUnits(amount1, 18),
        sqrtPriceX96: sqrtPriceX96,
        liquidity: liquidity,
        tick: tick,
      });
    }
  );
```

The type does not get assigned. What operation can I perform to assign the function arguments the Swap type.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code here to be a [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  Right now it's not self-contained, as it mentions a bunch of undeclared values (e.g., `ethers` and `poolContract`) and types (e.g., `BigNumber`).  It seems like the core of your question has to do with turning an object type into an arguments array, and you should be able to demonstrate this without externally-defined values and types.

Comment: Note that there is no inherent ordering of properties in  object types in TypeScript, so any conversion from object to tuple will require that you specify this ordering yourself.  Maybe like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wEBVkN). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer (if you would first [edit] the code to include a standalone example like I've shown here); if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

How was this `poolContract` get initialized? Its `on` function might not have the correct type assertion. For example, if your `poolContract` is created from a class `Contract` like this

```
class Contract {
   on: (name: string, fn: () => void)
}
```

The swap argument in your code will not be assigned to a type

Answer (score 0):

Its okay, what I ended up doing was declaring a const in the function and enforced the type as such:

```js
      const swap: Swap = {
        sender: sender,
        recipient: recipient,
        amount0: amount0,
        amount1: amount1,
        sqrtPriceX96: sqrtPriceX96,
        liquidity: liquidity,
        tick: tick,
      };
```

The `poolContract.on()` function comes from an external library.